# Solr core creation issue,Caused by: Lock held by this virtual machine:

Tags: solr

While trying to run the Solr provided sample the below issue faced:
ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'techproducts': Unable to create core [techproducts] Caused by: Lock held by this virtual machine: /usr/local/lib/solr-6.5.0/example/techproducts/solr/techproducts/data/index/write.lock

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved as the core was already there but not visible on admin UI. To resolve just delete the core and then try again. Below are the commands:

```
bin/solr delete -c techproducts
bin/solr start -e techproducts
```

Comment: I noticed that although I received this error creating the core, after refreshing the page, the core was there and there were no core initialization warnings.